# Can I use a union and bitfield for data packing

Tags: gcc, c++14

I'm creating a 4 bit and 8 bit colour encoding for font. This includes a foreground, background, style, and format. My hope is to use the following struct to represent the data in a 4-byte pack. My intent is to extract it as a single `uint32_t` that can be converted to binary data and saved in a file.

This is what I currently have:

```
struct font_pack {
    uint8_t : 8;
    struct {
        uint8_t format : 4;
        uint8_t style : 4;
    } header;
    uint8_t foreground;
    uint8_t background;
}
```

The header contains two half-bytes. `format` says the colour codes are either 4-bit or 8-bit colour. `style` is a bit flag set that declares formatter such as bolding and underline.

I am then using the following `union` to get the raw binary for both writing to file, as well to set or print the data as hex.

```
union font_raw {
    font_pack pack;
    uint32_t data;
}
```

Unfortunately when I print out the hex I get `0x04032100` when I was expecting `0x00120304`. Which makes me feel like byte alignment is not guaranteed within a `union` and endianness is catching me. I was really just hoping to have simple method of packing and unpacking the data into 3 bytes.

Is there any other easy way to do it or am I stuck with making a more traditional function that does the packing and unpacking?

Comment: What is `sizeof(font_pack)`?

Comment: by using the C++ standard `uint8_t` data structures, `font_pack` is a reliable 4 bytes. Which fits perfectly within the `uint32_t` in the union.

Comment: What makes you think it is not working? I assigned values to the fields, saved data to a uint32_t, created a new font_raw, assigned data from the uint32_t and the fields were correct. Why the need to fit it in 3 bytes in a specific order?

Comment: In order to read and write the data to a binary stream, it would need to be in the correct order or the fields will get reversed depending on the compiler and platform. So right now for me, the hex output is in reverse order of the font_pack's declaration order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an endianness issue, for sure. I'm guessing you're on x86/x64 (Intel-like) architecture, which is little-endian and will pack bytes from least-significant to most significant. Provided you are writing and reading the data on the same architecture (so little-endian systems) the endianness will ensure you get byte packing read back in the same order, so your `font_pack` members should still come out correctly. However if you'll be loading these files on a big-endian system you'll need to go the more traditional route. But if you're on the same endian-ness guaranteed, I'd go with your method. It's nicely elegant :)

edit: If you *are* reading or writing between different endianness machines, then you could always do something like the following:

```
#ifdef LITTLE_ENDIAN
struct font_pack {
    uint8_t : 8;
    struct {
        uint8_t format : 4;
        uint8_t style : 4;
    } header;
    uint8_t foreground;
    uint8_t background;
}
#else
struct font_pack {
    uint8_t background;
    uint8_t foreground;
    struct {
        uint8_t format : 4;
        uint8_t style : 4;
    } header;
    uint8_t : 8;
}
#endif
```

And then define LITTLE_ENDIAN on your x86 or similar system, and not on the big-endian system. Hope that helps.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess if you compile for a particular architecture (i.e. x86_64) endianness will be guaranteed despite the physical hardware it runs on.

Comment: Yep. Doesn't hurt to keep it in mind though, especially when writing cross-platform code. I've been bitten by this before (PowerPC anyone?)